# Bezier curves imported with 64bit MAPublisher become angular?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, illustrator, mapublisher

The bezier curves in ArcGIS (10.4.1) become angular when I import them with 64bit MAPublisher 9.8 in Illustrator (CC2015)

Are there any settings to fix this?

[image].

[image]

Comment: What are the precise steps that you are performing when you try to do this?  You do not mention it but I am guessing that the Bezier curves are stored in a file geodatabase.

Comment: According to Avenza Support Bezier Curves stored in a geodatabase can be imported only with the 32-bit Version of Illustrator.

Comment: Is that what you are using?

Comment: No, I'm using the 64-bit Version. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll re-open this so that you can write a few sentence answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

As I comment above, I had contact with the Avenza Support in order to solve this issue. Bezier curves are not supported in the basic geodatabase readers (file or personal). Bezier curves can only be imported using the ESRI Geodatabase reader which is only available in combination with the 32-bit version of illustrator.

Comment: You could run a tool like [densify](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/densify.htm) on the lines prior to importing into Illustrator. You'd just have to play with the settings to find the right number of points